# How to remove rows from UITableView using UISearchBar?

Tags: ios

I have usual `UITableView` with custom cell with `UISearchBar` and i can use **searchBar:textDidChange** method to filter rows.But what i want to add to my project is an ability to remove filtered rows that these rows will be removed from the original **DataSourseArray**
How can I implement this?

Comment: what do you use as dataSource? With coreData for example you can use the NSFetchedResultsController for automatic handling ;)

Comment: i use usual NSMutableArray and another mutalbeArray for filteredDataSourse

Answer (score 0):

If you have search bar you will have to filter data depending if filter is empty or not. 
Ity is handy to hold filtered data and full collection separetly:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* allTableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* filteredTableData;
```

Depending if filter is defind you will need to return diffrend cell count

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
    int rowCount;
    if(self.isFiltered)
        rowCount = filteredTableData.count;
    else
        rowCount = allTableData.count;

    return rowCount;
}
```

And same with returning cell. If there is filter - you have to use index aginst filtered data

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Food* food;
    if(isFiltered)
        food = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
        food = [allTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // ... Set up the cell here...;

    return cell;
}
```

[Here is tutorial](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/) on filtering UITableView

Comment: i use usual NSMutalbeArray and another mutableArray for filteredDataSourse

Comment: Please see attached tutorial. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is `[aryAll removeObjectsInArray:aryFilter];` to remove all and tell the `tableView` to `reloadData`.

Or to remove single, add

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete )
    {
        NSObject *obj = [aryFilter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [aryFilter removeObject:obj];
        [aryAll removeObject:obj];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

for example ;)

Haven't tried it in my code, but something like this you will need :)

Comment: hope this works like it shall :) if yes, please set answer as accepted. if not, tell where you still have problems and I will see how you can be helped ;)

Comment: yes-this works like i expected:)but how can i set answer as accepted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about is a short explanation :) use the V below the up- and down vote buttons (and possibly vote up ;D) to accept (the checkmark will appear as green after that :) )

Comment: I am new here so i dont have 15 reputation to vote up, but when i have i'll mark answer as accepted :)

Comment: @Igor, you can accept an answer before you have 15 rep.  Just click on the hollow check mark next to the answer to turn it green.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said you are using 2 different arrays.One for complete data and one for filtered data.Use a single array and this can be achieved easily

In other words.When you filter add the objects to the filtered array and then remove all objects from datasource array and add from filtered array and display it with reloaddata.